# More efficient way of replacing dates with first day of a given week

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, dplyr

From a list of dates, I'm interested in selecting a *first day of a week* and replicating that values *across the remaining days of the following week*. My current method of achieving this result makes use of an interim data frame and I'm interested in finding an improved method utilising dplyr [pipeline](/questions/tagged/pipeline) without the need to create an interim data set.

## Problem

### Data set

```
dta <- data.frame(origDate = seq(as.Date("01/01/2012", "%d/%m/%Y"),
                 as.Date("30/01/2012", "%d/%m/%Y"),
                 by = "day"))
```

### Interim data set

***I want to get rid of this step.***

```
# Libraries
require(dplyr); require(lubridate); require(tidyr)
# Create interim data set
dtaIn  <- dta %>%
    mutate(weeknum = week(origDate)) %>%
    mutate(yearnum = year(origDate)) %>%
    unite(weekAndYear, yearnum, weeknum, sep = "_") %>%
    arrange(origDate) %>%
    group_by(weekAndYear) %>%
    filter(row_number() == 1)
```

### Final data set

```
# Final data set
dtaFin <- dta %>%
    mutate(weeknum = week(origDate)) %>%
    mutate(yearnum = year(origDate)) %>%
    unite(weekAndYear, yearnum, weeknum, sep = "_") %>%
    left_join(y = dtaIn, by = c("weekAndYear" = "weekAndYear"))
```

## Results

```
>> dtaFin
   origDate.x weekAndYear origDate.y
1  2012-01-01      2012_1 2012-01-01
2  2012-01-02      2012_1 2012-01-01
3  2012-01-03      2012_1 2012-01-01
4  2012-01-04      2012_1 2012-01-01
5  2012-01-05      2012_1 2012-01-01
6  2012-01-06      2012_1 2012-01-01
7  2012-01-07      2012_1 2012-01-01
8  2012-01-08      2012_2 2012-01-08
9  2012-01-09      2012_2 2012-01-08
```

Results return first day of a week replicated across the week. The task is to arrive at the analgous results *without* the need to create `dtain` and *without* the leaving the ongoing `dplyr` [pipeline](/questions/tagged/pipeline). In practice, the code should look

```
dtaFin <- dta %>%
   # Create variable for first day of each week
   # Replicate across rows for that week
   # Return data.frame of the sime sizes + 1 column with new day
```

*The `weekAndYear` column can be removed from the final data set; I left here for the sake of reproducibility.*

Comment: With `data.table`, I think `data.table(dta)[,.(origDate, weekAndYear = sprintf("%d_%d", week(origDate), year(origDate))),][,weekBegin := min(origDate), by = .(weekAndYear)][]` should work. But you are only interested in `dplyr` solutions specifically?

Comment: @nrussell Thanks for showing the interest. Yes, it's mostly a workflow question that boils down to: *add column with first day of given week.* I've other things in this workflow and I need this column, I can do it via new object (as shown) but it seems wasteful to create object only for that.

Comment: I really don't work with `dplyr` much, but there seems to be limited(?) support for [windowing functions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/window-functions.html). E.g., in TSQL I would just do `MIN(origDate) OVER (PARTITION BY weekAndYear) AS weekBegin`; you may or may not be able to accomplish this with `dplyr` windowing operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is to use `strftime` to create the weekandyear var, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)
dta %>% 
  mutate(weekandyear = strftime(origDate+1, "%Y-%W")) %>% 
  group_by(weekandyear) %>% 
  mutate(origDate.y = head(origDate,1))

#     origDate weekandyear origDate.y
#       <date>       <chr>     <date>
#1  2012-01-01     2012-01 2012-01-01
#2  2012-01-02     2012-01 2012-01-01
#3  2012-01-03     2012-01 2012-01-01
#4  2012-01-04     2012-01 2012-01-01
#5  2012-01-05     2012-01 2012-01-01
#6  2012-01-06     2012-01 2012-01-01
```

Note there is no need for the first `mutate` (as @akrun mentions) so we can include it in the `group_by` statement, i.e.

```
dta %>%
 group_by(weekandyear = strftime(origDate+1, "%Y-%W")) %>%
 mutate(origDate.y = head(origDate,1))
```

Comment: Would you care to add why you need `origDate+1`?

Comment: So it won't start from 0 but from 1

Comment: You could remove the first `mutate` step and use that in the `group_by` statement